# How to count dynamically added inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form with two text boxes: One for peoples "name" and the other for their "surname". On the page you can click and it will add two more text boxes below, also for "name" and "surname".. so basically you could add as many pairs of name and surname as you want.

How do I count how many pairs/rows (of "names" and "surnames") of inputs?

You can see the demo here: http://poostudios.com/jstest2.html

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="nutrition/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        div{
        padding:8px;
        }
</style>enter code here

</head>

<body>

<form action="results.php" method="get">


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
 .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Name : </label>' +
  '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
  '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ><label> Surname : </label>' +
  '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
  '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');


newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

counter++;
});

$("#removeButton").click(function () {

counter--;
$("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

});


});
</script>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
<label>Name : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
<label>Surname : </label> <input type='textbox' id='textbox2' >
</div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton'>

<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('input').length / 2` ((jQuery: `$('input')`).  Refine your selection by putting the inputs in a particular `div` or other container and use `document.querySelectorAll('#specialDiv input')` to get your array (jQuery: `$('#specialDiv input')`)

Comment: or you could give each `input` a CSS `class` of `textbox`, and do `document.getElementsByClassName('textbox').length / 2`. Or, if you prefer jQuery, `$('input:not([type=submit])').length / 2` or, to be more specific, `$('#TextBoxesGroup').children().length` would work fine too.

Comment: @Tibrogargan just realised, `getElementsByTagName` will count OP's `input type="button"` and `input type="submit"` elements as well if called from `document` — needs to be `document.getElementById('TextBoxesGroup').getElementsByTagName('input')`

Comment: Your `newTextBoxDiv.after().html()` code appears to create two elements with the same `id` attribute, `"textbox' + counter + '"`, each time it is run. Each `id` should be unique throughout the entire page. You should not use the same `id` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of ways to do this. @Tibrogargan and I have littered the comments on your question with various snippets which will return the number of elements at any given time.

However, each time you want to check the count, you'd need to call those methods in full to get a 'live' count — so if you're just planning to check the number of inputs once, i.e. when the form is submitted, for example, all you need do is, in your submit handler, check the count or store the count in a variable:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // store the current count in a variable (this will not change if the user adds another input)
  var current_count = $('#TextBoxesGroup input').length / 2;

  // do what you want with the current_count variable
  console.log("The user has submitted the form with " + current_count + " input fields");

});
```

However, perhaps you're not only planning to count the number of input fields once. Perhaps you're monitoring the user's behaviour. In such a case, you could define a function to make things a bit less verbose.

Instead of using a counter which you increment/decrement, just define a `counter` function in the following way:

```
function counter(){
    return $('#TextBoxesGroup input').length / 2;
    /* 
      This could also be: 
        return document.getElementById('TextBoxesGroup').getElementsByTagName('input').length / 2;
    */
}
```

Now, whenever you need to check how many input pairs there are, just call `counter()` and the value will be returned. So, let's imagine you're checking the number of inputs when the user clicks something — your code might look like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type=button]', function(){


  // conditionally pass the current count straight to a function which uses the data
  if ( counter() > 0 ) processMyData( counter() );

  // or, if you process the data here, then pass it on to another function
  // store the current count
  var current_count = counter();

  // do nothing if there are no input fields
  if ( current_count < 1 ) return;

  // do what you want with the count now that you have it
  myAnalytics.inputs.save( current_count );

  // do something else with it
  processMyData( current_count );      

  // etc.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery already, this is how you are going to get the length. Divide by 2 since each you have a set of name and username.

```
<script>
    var len = $('#TextBoxesGroup').find('input').length / 2;
    // Do whatever you wanted to do with the len
</script>
```

Here is the [plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/jVi4AZBbWNE0qOzZIB8R?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your code, the ids are not unique so I modified it a bit just see the demo below ( I used the `append()` function for your markup creation ).

Secondly since you used a counter variable just use it to count the number of pairs by dividing it with 2 (`counter / 2`).

```js
var counter = 2;
$("#addButton").click(function() {
    $('<div>', {
     id : 'TextBoxDiv' + counter
    }).append(
     $('<label>', {
            text: 'Name : '
        }),
        $('<input>', {
            type: 'text',
            name: 'textbox' + (++counter), // increment counter for name
            id: 'textbox' + counter,
            value: ''
        }),
        $('<label>', {
            text: 'Surname : '
        }),
        $('<input>', {
            type: 'text',
            name: 'textbox' + (++counter), // increment counter for surname
            id: 'textbox' + counter,
            value: ''
        })
    ).appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup');
    
    // just divide the counter by 2 to get the pairs
    console.log('input text pairs: ' + counter/2);
});

$("#removeButton").click(function() {
    // if counter === 2 (initial) then remove nothing
    if (counter === 2) {
     return false;
    }

    // decrement counter by 2
    // and remove the textbox container
    counter-=2;
    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
    console.log('input text pairs: ' + counter/2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="results.php" method="get">
    <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
        <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
            <label>Name : </label>
            <input type='textbox' id='textbox1'>
            <label>Surname : </label>
            <input type='textbox' id='textbox2'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton'>
    <input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton'>

    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

$("#textbox1").length will give you the count of occurrences of name text field.