# How can I remove an HTML element using javascript in this specific situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script, it has two tasks:

1. add/remove dynamic input box element, let's call that 'input_box_a'.
2. add/remove one value on the input box, lets call it 'input_box_b'

so lets say there is an empty input box, whenever I click add it adds 1, and when I click remove it remove 1.

Now, doing task one, which is adding/removing input box, also adds and remove value to the 'input_box_b'.

My problem is, lets say I click add button on task two three times, it would put 3 values on the 'input_box_b', and when I add three input box using task one, it would add 3 more additional value, the total now is 6, if I clicked remove button on the task two, three times, it would subtract 3 values.

What I want is when I click the remove button, on task two, for the fourth time, I also want to remove the input boxes that were previously added using task one.

Here is my reference for this code this is basically what it does, 
[How to count dynamically added inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457305/how-to-count-dynamically-added-inputs)

https://plnkr.co/edit/jVi4AZBbWNE0qOzZIB8R?p=preview&preview

**Here is the script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var $input = $("#b_size");
  var maxRows = 20;
  var x = 1;

  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_title[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" name="b_page[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_author[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_publication[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_type[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" name="b_price[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</span>  <
    /button></td > < /tr> </div > ';

  $input.val(0);

  $(".alter").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('plus_one'))
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    else if ($input.val() >= 1)

      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) - 1);

    else if ($input.val() == 0) // This part
      $("#b_table").on('change', function(e) { //is just 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); // what I assume
        x--; // to be 
      }); // the solution

  });

  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#b_table").append(html);
      x++;
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    }
  });

  $("#b_table").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    x--;
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) - 1);
  });

});
```

**Here is the HTML code on task one:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-repsonsive" id="b_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Page</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Publication</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th><button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**And here is the HTML code for task two:**

```
 <div class="input-group-append" role="group" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="b_size" id="b_size"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary alter plus_one"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger alter minus_one"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
  </div>
```

**And last, here is the work in progress to help you visualize:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var $input = $("#b_size");
  var maxRows = 20;
  var x = 1;

  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_title[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" name="b_page[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_author[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_publication[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_type[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" step=0.01 name="b_price[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</span></button></td></tr> </div>';

  $input.val(0);

  $(".alter").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('plus_one'))
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    else if ($input.val() >= 1)
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) - 1);
  });

  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#b_table").append(html);
      x++;
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    }
  });

  $("#b_table").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    x--;
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) - 1);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Number of Books</label>
  <input type="text" id="b_size" />
  <button type="button" class="alter plus_one">ADD</button>
  <button type="button" class="alter minus_one">REMOVE</button>
</div>

<table id="b_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Page</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Publication</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th><button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't use `id="remove"` in every row. Change that to a class and your code will work.

Comment: Im not sure I follow, but in my example https://jsfiddle.net/aaa28/oamves7g/7/ , 'remove' is working fine, what I need is when the value of input_box_b hits zero, I also want to remove the added input_box_a from the task 1

Comment: Isn't that what `$(this).closest("tr").remove()` does?

Comment: when I click the add, it add an input box or a table row, and at the same time, it also add a value in 'input_box_b' , and when I click the remove button it removes a value in input_box_b. Now there is another 'add' and 'remove' button beside input_box_b, and what it does also add and remove values.

Comment: I don't understand why you have two Add buttons, and why there's a Remove button in the first line. The buttons on the first line just update the counter, they don't do anything to the table, what's the point of that?

Comment: I apologize, honestly I am having difficulty expressing myself and explaining my objectives.

Comment: The scenario is, when a user have books, he/she can add those book title using the input_box_a, and automatically count those, let say there are three books, Carrie, Dune and On the Road, so that is 3 books in total, which will appear on the input_box_b. Now, let say the user have another book, but he/she does not recall the title, he/she cannot input that on the input_box_a, but the book count is important, so instead he/she just increment the number of books using the input_box_b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209398/discussion-between-aaa28-and-barmar).

Comment: Questions should be potentially useful to others visiting this site; asking about "this specific situation" with your own unique script doesn't meet that standard.  This should be reduced to a minimal example, so that it's likely that someone else will have the same problem.

Comment: Confusing question :) What's working and what's not ? I think it would be better if you explain the issue with words/schema than inputs and task 1/2... Do you expect to generate inputs for each book and that the "inline" remove button would remove only it's appropriate "inline" record ?

Comment: @Brilliand I think you have a point, but this is my opinion, everyone have their own unique situation, but as you can see in my posted question I referenced a previous question from this site that almost exactly the same as to what I want, it just need a little hacking and modification, so we cannot really tell what information can be helpful and useful to others or not.

Comment: @Bilel actually , Barmar get it right, but just little modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When decrementing the counter, check if it's less than the number of rows in the table. If it is, remove the last row.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var $input = $("#b_size");
  var maxRows = 20;
  var x = 1;

  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_title[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" name="b_page[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_author[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_publication[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="b_type[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" step=0.01 name="b_price[]" class="form-control"/></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</span></button></td></tr> </div>';

  $input.val(0);

  $(".alter").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('plus_one'))
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    else if ($input.val() >= 1) {
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) - 1);
      if ($input.val() < $("#b_table tr:has(input)").length) {
        $("#b_table tr:has(input)").last().remove();
      }
    }
  });

  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    if (x <= maxRows) {
      $("#b_table").append(html);
      x++;
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    }
  });

  $("#b_table").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    x--;
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) - 1);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Number of Books</label>
  <input type="text" id="b_size" />
  <button type="button" class="alter plus_one">ADD</button>
  <button type="button" class="alter minus_one">REMOVE</button>
</div>

<table id="b_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Page</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Publication</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th><button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is working as intended, though there is a minor or slight issue, let say there is 3 values on box B and also 3 input fields, when I remove 1 value, it became 2 so it is less than the number of the input box, what it does is it removes everything, where there should still be two input box left. Ok maybe I am pushing it, but this will do just fine, thank you very much.

Comment: If it doesn't remove all of them, how does it know which one to remove?

Comment: I thought it was strange to remove everything, but I asked if that's what you wanted and I thought you said yes.

Comment: I apologize again, I am not good in communicating. Now that you mentioned, I wonder the same thing, and it made me confused.

Comment: it is fine if the value of box B is more than the number of input fields or box A, what is not fine is that if the number of input box is more than the number of value in box B. Is there  a way to remove the box A one at a time?

Comment: I changed it to remove the last row using `.last()`.

Comment: I notice another thing, I am sorry, but let say I add 5 input box, then remove it using box B, when I try to add again, I cannot add anymore, or it is limited to a number, let just say three or two, input box, and not the maxrow number

Comment: You don't update `x` in the `.alter` click handler.

Comment: ok thanks, I can now finally say, it is now working the way I want to